# Text and DIVS centered on Chrome, but not iPod?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am creating a webApp for a golf calculator and when testing on my iPod, it seems the text and div tags are not centered like they are on Chrome. Then Inputs and Select tags however are. Here is my html/css

```
<header>
    <h1>Simple Handicap Calculator</h1>
</header>

<section>
    <input id="score1" class="score" type="tel" value="Score" onfocus="this.value = '';">
    <input id="score2" class="score" type="tel" value="Score" onfocus="this.value = '';">
    <input id="score3" class="score" type="tel" value="Score" onfocus="this.value = '';">
    <div class="rating">Course</div>
    <select id="courseRating" class="select"></select>
    <div class="rating">Slope</div>
    <select id="slopeRating" class="select"></select>
    <div class="calculateButton" onclick="HandicapCalculator.CalculateHandicap();">Tap</div>
    <div id="handicap">Handicap</div>
    <div id="curtain"></div>
</section>
```

And then my css:

```
html {
font-size: 1em;
background: #825534;
color: #E6D4A7;
font-family: JosefinSlab;
}
header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
font-size: 32px;
text-align: center;

font-weight: bold;

text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #36362C;
}
section {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
section .score {
height: 38px;
width: 50%;
margin: 8px 25% 0 25%;
padding: none;

text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
background: #5D917D;

box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #36362C;
border: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;

}

section .rating {
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 8px 25% 0 25%;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #36362C;
text-align: center;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
section .select {
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 8px 25% 0 25%;
padding: none;

background: #5D917D;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #36362C;

font-size: 1.5em;
text-indent: 40%;
border: none; 
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}

section .calculateButton {
float: left;
height: 50px;
width: 50%;

margin: 8px 25% 0 25%;

background: #A8AD80;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #36362C;

color: #36362C;
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;


}
section #curtain {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

background: #000;
opacity: .6;
}
section #handicap {
float: left;
height: 50px;
width: 70%;

margin: 8px 15% 0 15%;
background: #E6D4A7;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #36362C;

color: #36362C;
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

If there is anything else I can provide, just let me know. For a live testing version, ragstudio.com/handicapCalculator

Comment: Works on android phone. Problem occurs on the ipad retina as well

Comment: you must make use of `media queries` for a responsive design on mobiles/iphones/tablets/ipad etc..

Comment: @vishalkin In most cases yes. Being that this is developed on %'s not fixed pixels, the layout will be similar for the targeted devices.

Comment: even though your `width: x%` is in % but the elements like `font-size` are not.. and that will create conflict in your responsive designing.

Comment: Probably off topic, but why are you doing `float:left; width:100%` for some things? I'm not sure what that would achieve.

Comment: Yes, having width at 100% and a float set would be redundant,  further css stylings if the change the width would float. Just a practice of mine I suppose.

Comment: @vishalkin removing the text and css for the font size did not fix the issue

Comment: @StephenRaghunath: This link may help you: [Respsive Design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)

Comment: @vishalkin I fully understand the concepts of responsive design. Which is why using percentages would be considered responsive. The issue here is that the iOS rendering of percentages in my situation is inaccurate.